# grab element of a list R

Tags: r, list, element

Hi I have the following data structure:

```
typeof(snp.seq)
[1] "list"

typeof(snp.seq[1])
[1] "list"

snp.seq[[1]]    
[1]"MYSFNTLRLYLWETIVFFSLAASKEAEAARSAPKPMSPSDFLDKLMGRTSGYDARIRPNFKGPPVNVSCNIFINSFGSIAETTMDYRVNIFLRQQWN DPRLAYNEYPDDSLDLDPSMLDSIWKPDLFFANEKGAHFHEITTDNKLLRISRNGNVLYSIRITLTLACPMDLKNFPMDVQTCIMQLESFGYTMNDLIFEWQEQGAVQVADGLTLPQFILKEEKDLRYCTKHYNTGKFTCIEARFHLERQMGYYLIQMYIPSLLIVILSWISFWINMDAAPARVGLGITTVLTMTTQSSGSRASLPKVSYVKAIDIWMAVCLLFVFSALLEYAAVNFVSRQHKELLRFRRKRRHHKSPMLNLFQEDEAGEGRFNFSAYGMGPACLQAKDGISVKGANNSNTTNPPPAPSKSPEEMRKLFIQRAKKIDKISRIGFPMAFLIFNMFYWIIYKIVRREDVHNQ"



typeof(snp.seq[[1]])

"character"

> dput(snp.seq)
list("MYSFNTLRLYLWETIVFFSLAASKEAEAARSAPKPMSPSDFLDKLMGRTSGYDARIRPNFKGPPVNVSCNIFINSFGSIAETTMDYRVNIFLRQQWNDPRLAYNEYPDDSLDLDPSMLDSIWKPDLFFANEKGAHFHEITTDNKLLRISRNGNVLYSIRITLTLACPMDLKNFPMDVQTCIMQLESFGYTMNDLIFEWQEQGAVQVADGLTLPQFILKEEKDLRYCTKHYNTGKFTCIEARFHLERQMGYYLIQMYIPSLLIVILSWISFWINMDAAPARVGLGITTVLTMTTQSSGSRASLPKVSYVKAIDIWMAVCLLFVFSALLEYAAVNFVSRQHKELLRFRRKRRHHKSPMLNLFQEDEAGEGRFNFSAYGMGPACLQAKDGISVKGANNSNTTNPPPAPSKSPEEMRKLFIQRAKKIDKISRIGFPMAFLIFNMFYWIIYKIVRREDVHNQ", 
    "MYSFNTLRLYLWETIVFFSLAASKEAEAARSAPKPMSPSDFLDKLMGRTSGYDARIRPNFKGPPVNVSCNIFINSFGSIAETTMDYRVNIFLRQQWNDPRLAYNEYPDDSLDLDPSMLDSIWKPDLFFANEKGAHFHEITTDNKLLRISRNGNVLYSIRITLTLACPMDLKNFPMDVQTCIMQLESFGYTMNDLIFEWQEQGAVQVADGLTLPQFILKEEKDLRYCTKHYNTGKFTCIEARFHLERQMGYYLIQMYIPSLLIVILSWISFWINMDAAPARVGLGITTVLTMTTQSSGSRASLPKGPV", 
    "MDYRVNIFLRQQWNDPRLAYNEYPDDSLDLDPSMLDSIWKPDLFFANEKGAHFHEITTDNKLLRISRNGNVLYSIRITLTLACPMDLKNFPMDVQTCIMQLESFGYTMNDLIFEWQEQGAVQVADGLTLPQFILKEEKDLRYCTKHYNTGKFTCIEARFHLERQMGYYLIQMYIPSLLIVILSWISFWINMDAAPARVGLGITTVLTMTTQSSGSRASLPKVSYVKAIDIWMAVCLLFVFSALLEYAAVNFVSRQHKELLRFRRKRRHHKEDEAGEGRFNFSAYGMGPACLQAKDGISVKGANNSNTTNPPPAPSKSPEEMRKLFIQRAKKIDKISRIGFPMAFLIFNMFYWIIYKIVRREDVHNQ", 
    "MDYRVNIFLRQQWNDPRLAYNEYPDDSLDLDPSMLDSIWKPDLFFANEKGAHFHEITTDNKLLRISRNGNVLYSIRITLTLACPMDLKNFPMDVQTCIMQLESFGYTMNDLIFEWQEQGAVQVADGLTLPQFILKEEKDLRYCTKHYNTGKFTCIEARFHLERQMGYYLIQMYIPSLLIVILSWISFWINMDAAPARVGLGITTVLTMTTQSSGSRASLPKVSYVKAIDIWMAVCLLFVFSALLEYAAVNFVSRQHKELLRFRRKRRHHKEDEAGEGRFNFSAYGMGPACLQAKDGISVKGANNSNTTNPPPAPSKSPEEMRKLFIQRAKKIDKISRIGFPMAFLIFNMFYWIIYKIVRREDVHNQ", 
    "MYSFNTLRLYLWETIVFFSLAASKEAEAARSAPKPMSPSDFLDKLMGRTSGYDARIRPNFKGPPVNVSCNIFINSFGSIAETTMDYRVNIFLRQQWNDPRLAYNEYPDDSLDLDPSMLDSIWKPDLFFANEKGAHFHEITTDNKLLRISRNGNVLYSIRITLTLACPMDLKNFPMDVQTCIMQLESFGYTMNDLIFEWQEQGAVQVADGLTLPQFILKEEKDLRYCTKHYNTGKFTCIEARFHLERQMGYYLIQMYIPSLLIVILSWISFWINMDAAPARVGLGITTVLTMTTQSSGSRASLPKVSYVKAIDIWMAVCLLFVFSALLEYAAVNFVSRQHKELLRFRRKRRHHKEDEAGEGRFNFSAYGMGPACLQAKDGISVKGANNSNTTNPPPAPSKSPEEMRKLFIQRAKKIDKISRIGFPMAFLIFNMFYWIIYKIVRREDVHNQ")
```

where `snp.seq` is of type `list`, and each element of `snp.seq` is also a `list` - as demonstrated in the example.

What I need to do is to specify a number, and return the corresponding letter from the sequence in `snp.seq[[1]]`.

i.e. position 1 is the letter 'M'

I have tried to call it by doing

```
snp.seq[[1,1]]]
snp.seq[[1],[1]]
```

of which both do not work as they are calling a position which is out of bounds.

How would I call any letter by giving a number (it's position in the sequence)?

Thanks

Comment: this is returning the entire string. is there a better function than "typeof" which can better describe my data type? I suspect I am not providing the full definition. all I can say is that it appears as a nested list.

Comment: typeof(snp.seq[[1]]) is a character. does this change things?

Comment: That is a single string, not a nested list.  you can use `substring`  and `grep` to pick out the characters

Comment: It may be easier to solve this if you post dput(snp.seq) or its sample here?

Comment: have added this into the question

Comment: You may want to read about `[[` indexing.  If x is a list, first level `x[]` is used to view/get the names of the elements within the list, and `x[1]` therefore is still a list. If there are no names, you will see `[[1]]`. Your `class(x[[1]])` is `character`.  It's a vector.

Comment: You can give each letter an index with `seq(nchar(x))`. Also, you should be using `class` instead of `typeof`  for stuff like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the data in your example -

```
snp.seq <- list("MYSFNTLRLYLWETIVFFSLAASKEAEAARSAPKPMSPSDFLDKLMGRTSGYDARIRPNFKGPPVNVSCNIFINSFGSIAETTMDYRVNIFLRQQWNDPRLAYNEYPDDSLDLDPSMLDSIWKPDLFFANEKGAHFHEITTDNKLLRISRNGNVLYSIRITLTLACPMDLKNFPMDVQTCIMQLESFGYTMNDLIFEWQEQGAVQVADGLTLPQFILKEEKDLRYCTKHYNTGKFTCIEARFHLERQMGYYLIQMYIPSLLIVILSWISFWINMDAAPARVGLGITTVLTMTTQSSGSRASLPKVSYVKAIDIWMAVCLLFVFSALLEYAAVNFVSRQHKELLRFRRKRRHHKSPMLNLFQEDEAGEGRFNFSAYGMGPACLQAKDGISVKGANNSNTTNPPPAPSKSPEEMRKLFIQRAKKIDKISRIGFPMAFLIFNMFYWIIYKIVRREDVHNQ", 
                "MYSFNTLRLYLWETIVFFSLAASKEAEAARSAPKPMSPSDFLDKLMGRTSGYDARIRPNFKGPPVNVSCNIFINSFGSIAETTMDYRVNIFLRQQWNDPRLAYNEYPDDSLDLDPSMLDSIWKPDLFFANEKGAHFHEITTDNKLLRISRNGNVLYSIRITLTLACPMDLKNFPMDVQTCIMQLESFGYTMNDLIFEWQEQGAVQVADGLTLPQFILKEEKDLRYCTKHYNTGKFTCIEARFHLERQMGYYLIQMYIPSLLIVILSWISFWINMDAAPARVGLGITTVLTMTTQSSGSRASLPKGPV", 
                "MDYRVNIFLRQQWNDPRLAYNEYPDDSLDLDPSMLDSIWKPDLFFANEKGAHFHEITTDNKLLRISRNGNVLYSIRITLTLACPMDLKNFPMDVQTCIMQLESFGYTMNDLIFEWQEQGAVQVADGLTLPQFILKEEKDLRYCTKHYNTGKFTCIEARFHLERQMGYYLIQMYIPSLLIVILSWISFWINMDAAPARVGLGITTVLTMTTQSSGSRASLPKVSYVKAIDIWMAVCLLFVFSALLEYAAVNFVSRQHKELLRFRRKRRHHKEDEAGEGRFNFSAYGMGPACLQAKDGISVKGANNSNTTNPPPAPSKSPEEMRKLFIQRAKKIDKISRIGFPMAFLIFNMFYWIIYKIVRREDVHNQ", 
                "MDYRVNIFLRQQWNDPRLAYNEYPDDSLDLDPSMLDSIWKPDLFFANEKGAHFHEITTDNKLLRISRNGNVLYSIRITLTLACPMDLKNFPMDVQTCIMQLESFGYTMNDLIFEWQEQGAVQVADGLTLPQFILKEEKDLRYCTKHYNTGKFTCIEARFHLERQMGYYLIQMYIPSLLIVILSWISFWINMDAAPARVGLGITTVLTMTTQSSGSRASLPKVSYVKAIDIWMAVCLLFVFSALLEYAAVNFVSRQHKELLRFRRKRRHHKEDEAGEGRFNFSAYGMGPACLQAKDGISVKGANNSNTTNPPPAPSKSPEEMRKLFIQRAKKIDKISRIGFPMAFLIFNMFYWIIYKIVRREDVHNQ", 
                "MYSFNTLRLYLWETIVFFSLAASKEAEAARSAPKPMSPSDFLDKLMGRTSGYDARIRPNFKGPPVNVSCNIFINSFGSIAETTMDYRVNIFLRQQWNDPRLAYNEYPDDSLDLDPSMLDSIWKPDLFFANEKGAHFHEITTDNKLLRISRNGNVLYSIRITLTLACPMDLKNFPMDVQTCIMQLESFGYTMNDLIFEWQEQGAVQVADGLTLPQFILKEEKDLRYCTKHYNTGKFTCIEARFHLERQMGYYLIQMYIPSLLIVILSWISFWINMDAAPARVGLGITTVLTMTTQSSGSRASLPKVSYVKAIDIWMAVCLLFVFSALLEYAAVNFVSRQHKELLRFRRKRRHHKEDEAGEGRFNFSAYGMGPACLQAKDGISVKGANNSNTTNPPPAPSKSPEEMRKLFIQRAKKIDKISRIGFPMAFLIFNMFYWIIYKIVRREDVHNQ")
##
getLetter <- function(elem,pos){
  if(pos > nchar(snp.seq[[elem]])){
    stop("Position argument exceeds sequence length")
  } else {
    substr(snp.seq[[elem]],pos,pos)
  }
}
##
```

So to get the first letter for the first three elements in `snp.seq`, you would do

```
> getLetter(1,1)
[1] "M"
> getLetter(2,1)
[1] "M"
> getLetter(3,1)
[1] "M"
> substr(snp.seq[[1]],1,3)
[1] "MYS"
> substr(snp.seq[[2]],1,3)
[1] "MYS"
> substr(snp.seq[[3]],1,3)
[1] "MDY"
```

(sampling the first few letters of these elements to validate).

Comment: snp.seq[[1]] and snp.seq[[2]] both need to iterate from position 1. so this is almost it. could it be changed so that each element within snp.list can be iterated in it's own right, rather than merging all elements into one big list?

Comment: Sorry, I though it was a list a of one vector; I didn't see that there were five. When you say "each element can be iterate in its own right", do you mean being able to use the above function on a each of the five list elements (vectors)?

Comment: hi nrussell. yes that's it. sorry for not being specific enough. something like calling getLetter(1,1) where the first parameter is the list element, the second is the position in the sequence.

Comment: @brucezepplin, you can use `with` for that. `with(list, stuff)` means that I am basically inside the list doing stuff.  So the function should be okay if called as `with(list, getLetter(1,1))`.  `substring` is vectorized, so it should get the info for each string

Answer (score 1):

You could use `letter` from `Biostrings`

```
library(Biostrings)
 letter(snp.seq[[1]], 1)
 #[1] "M"
 letter(snp.seq[[3]], 3:1)
 #[1] "YDM"

 letter(snp.seq[[5]], 5:10)
 #[1] "NTLRLY"
```

Comment: this is convienient. Bioconductor is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
snp.seq <- list("MYSFNTLRLYLWETIVFFSLAASKEAEAARSAPKPMSPSDFLDKLMGRTSGYDARIRPNFKGPPVNVSCNIFINSFGSIAETTMDYRVNIFLRQQWNDPRLAYNEYPDDSLDLDPSMLDSIWKPDLFFANEKGAHFHEITTDNKLLRISRNGNVLYSIRITLTLACPMDLKNFPMDVQTCIMQLESFGYTMNDLIFEWQEQGAVQVADGLTLPQFILKEEKDLRYCTKHYNTGKFTCIEARFHLERQMGYYLIQMYIPSLLIVILSWISFWINMDAAPARVGLGITTVLTMTTQSSGSRASLPKVSYVKAIDIWMAVCLLFVFSALLEYAAVNFVSRQHKELLRFRRKRRHHKSPMLNLFQEDEAGEGRFNFSAYGMGPACLQAKDGISVKGANNSNTTNPPPAPSKSPEEMRKLFIQRAKKIDKISRIGFPMAFLIFNMFYWIIYKIVRREDVHNQ", 
                "MYSFNTLRLYLWETIVFFSLAASKEAEAARSAPKPMSPSDFLDKLMGRTSGYDARIRPNFKGPPVNVSCNIFINSFGSIAETTMDYRVNIFLRQQWNDPRLAYNEYPDDSLDLDPSMLDSIWKPDLFFANEKGAHFHEITTDNKLLRISRNGNVLYSIRITLTLACPMDLKNFPMDVQTCIMQLESFGYTMNDLIFEWQEQGAVQVADGLTLPQFILKEEKDLRYCTKHYNTGKFTCIEARFHLERQMGYYLIQMYIPSLLIVILSWISFWINMDAAPARVGLGITTVLTMTTQSSGSRASLPKGPV", 
                "MDYRVNIFLRQQWNDPRLAYNEYPDDSLDLDPSMLDSIWKPDLFFANEKGAHFHEITTDNKLLRISRNGNVLYSIRITLTLACPMDLKNFPMDVQTCIMQLESFGYTMNDLIFEWQEQGAVQVADGLTLPQFILKEEKDLRYCTKHYNTGKFTCIEARFHLERQMGYYLIQMYIPSLLIVILSWISFWINMDAAPARVGLGITTVLTMTTQSSGSRASLPKVSYVKAIDIWMAVCLLFVFSALLEYAAVNFVSRQHKELLRFRRKRRHHKEDEAGEGRFNFSAYGMGPACLQAKDGISVKGANNSNTTNPPPAPSKSPEEMRKLFIQRAKKIDKISRIGFPMAFLIFNMFYWIIYKIVRREDVHNQ", 
                "MDYRVNIFLRQQWNDPRLAYNEYPDDSLDLDPSMLDSIWKPDLFFANEKGAHFHEITTDNKLLRISRNGNVLYSIRITLTLACPMDLKNFPMDVQTCIMQLESFGYTMNDLIFEWQEQGAVQVADGLTLPQFILKEEKDLRYCTKHYNTGKFTCIEARFHLERQMGYYLIQMYIPSLLIVILSWISFWINMDAAPARVGLGITTVLTMTTQSSGSRASLPKVSYVKAIDIWMAVCLLFVFSALLEYAAVNFVSRQHKELLRFRRKRRHHKEDEAGEGRFNFSAYGMGPACLQAKDGISVKGANNSNTTNPPPAPSKSPEEMRKLFIQRAKKIDKISRIGFPMAFLIFNMFYWIIYKIVRREDVHNQ", 
                "MYSFNTLRLYLWETIVFFSLAASKEAEAARSAPKPMSPSDFLDKLMGRTSGYDARIRPNFKGPPVNVSCNIFINSFGSIAETTMDYRVNIFLRQQWNDPRLAYNEYPDDSLDLDPSMLDSIWKPDLFFANEKGAHFHEITTDNKLLRISRNGNVLYSIRITLTLACPMDLKNFPMDVQTCIMQLESFGYTMNDLIFEWQEQGAVQVADGLTLPQFILKEEKDLRYCTKHYNTGKFTCIEARFHLERQMGYYLIQMYIPSLLIVILSWISFWINMDAAPARVGLGITTVLTMTTQSSGSRASLPKVSYVKAIDIWMAVCLLFVFSALLEYAAVNFVSRQHKELLRFRRKRRHHKEDEAGEGRFNFSAYGMGPACLQAKDGISVKGANNSNTTNPPPAPSKSPEEMRKLFIQRAKKIDKISRIGFPMAFLIFNMFYWIIYKIVRREDVHNQ")
##

uls = unlist(snp.seq)

substr(uls,1,1)
[1] "M" "M" "M" "M" "M"

substr(uls,1,2)
[1] "MY" "MY" "MD" "MD" "MY"

substr(uls,3,5)
[1] "SFN" "SFN" "YRV" "YRV" "SFN"
```